# PHP array_filter gives me different outputs

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I've got this nice script with a lot of help working:

```
   if (isset($_POST['talente'])) { // array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" } 

    $talente = $_POST['talente']; 

    $myFile = fopen("talente.csv", "r"); // e.f.: name;1;-;stuff
    $csv = [];
    while ($data = fgetcsv($myFile, 1000, ";")) {
        $csv[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($myFile);

    $i = 0;
    $talentline = array_filter($csv, function($i) use ($talente) {
        return in_array($i, $talente--);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    $talentline = array_filter($talentline);
    $talentline = array_values($talentline);

}

$talentline[0][0] = isset($talentline[0][0]) ? $talentline[0][0] : ""; 
...
```

This works very well on my PC in localhost. But after uploading it on my host nothing happened. After printing and dumping a while I noticed, that every variable has the expected value/s but $talentline. When I set var_dump around it, it gives me a multi-dimensional array back as I expect it on PC. But on my Hoster only NULL. I couldn't find out why.

Comment: If it works on one but not another, then check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php then come back and add the error(s) in your question, should there be any. Could also be a permissions issue, PHP version, who knows.

Comment: Is `$talente` an array? If not, looks like it's an integer. http://php.net/in_array I don't see how your code would ever work.

Comment: No errors, not a single one. Yes, $talente is an array and as I wrote, it works on my personal localhost.

Comment: Then why do you try to decrement `$talente` -> `return in_array($i, $talente--);`

Comment: You'll find the explenation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190930/php-two-dimensional-array-with-empty-items

Comment: I'm confused. Your title reads as: *"PHP array_filter gives me different outputs"* then you later write: *"But after uploading it on my host nothing happened."* - This is rather confusing, wouldn't you agree? Plus, "how" are you checking for errors? and what does a var_dump reveal on POST? You're using a form for this and that could also be an issue and certain things could be failing on you *silently*.

Comment: Have both envs local and remote got the same php version?

Comment: Your other question as you linke above, contains `$_GET['talente']` and yours here has a POST array. Which in turn and as I said already, will fail on you "silently". POST usually uses a form with name attributes, you have no code to support the question. Your (unknown) form's method is unknown. Commenting is getting too long here. Post your full code.

Comment: I'd say an array and NULL are two different outputs, so I don't see why my title would be confusing, wouldn't you agree? I checked errors with "error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);" and checked every contant a variable has. How else would I know which variable is empty?

Comment: I used $_GET and $_POST which hat both the same outputs on both servers.

Comment: [Read this comment again...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193667/php-array-filter-gives-me-different-outputs#comment65728023_39193667), I made a few edits to it. I will delete this one shortly in order not to tie up the comments section as much as they are now. You may also have to use `empty()` rather than `isset()`, no idea what your values are.

Comment: I placed the given value of the $_Post which should be enough and less confusing than posting 3.000 lines of codes the complete project has currently because of FPDF.

Comment: You also need to "display" those errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - or check your logs. There isn't anything else I can come up with. You'll need to wait for someone else, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov Thank you! There was a little difference and now everything is running! Never thought this minor update would change so much.

Comment: @KendelVentonda Do you mean php version difference? If yes which versions do you have?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, I had something around 5.6.1x and the version online was 5.6.23